# Why's BeautifulSoup soup.find() function returning None when trying to grab class names/ids?

Tags: python, debugging, web-scraping

Hey guys in Python I'm trying to scrape a website but when I run `print(week)` which contains a class name (`some-class-name`)
to the display what's inside the class, I get `None` as the output.

I've tried putting in a different class name on the site just to see if something would print via `print(week)` and I indeed saw some output of the console containing HTML code so they functionality works fine.

Is it because the website's layered with good security on this particular part of the website?  I could be wrong, that was my initial thought I received that output.

I've read around on some other posts regarding this but it wasn't clear to me.  Below is some of my code reference.

How can I successfully display what's inside of `some-class-name`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('some-website.com')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')  # parse as HTML page, this is the source code of the page
week = soup.find(class_='some-class-name')

print(week)
```

Comment: maybe the content is brought by javascript ... in that case you should use selenium

Comment: expanding on @GiovaniSalazar an easy way to see if the class you are looking for is available is to check  `page.text`. If its not you can try and figure out which secondary request is pulling the content in and then make that request instead of `requests.get('some-website.com')`.

Comment: Share the actual url and indicate expected output.